# Making a program runnable

Tags: java, executorservice

Below is my program. I want to use a `ExecutorService` on it to run once a day. However, the program is not 'runnable' please advice the necessary change to make it so.

```
package priceCollector;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

public class App extends myTimerTask  {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Date now = new Date();
        DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateInstance();
        String s = df.format(now);

        String fileName = new String();

        fileName = "/Users/Desktop/" + s + ".csv";

        URL link = null;

        try {
            link = new URL("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=III.L+ADM.L+AAL.L+ANTO.L+AHT.L+ABF.L+AZN.L+AV.L+BAB.L+BA.L+BARC.L+BDEV.L+BLT.L+BP.L+BATS.L+BLND.L+BTA.L+BNZL.L+BRBY.L+CPI.L+CCL.L+CNA.L+CCH.L+CPG.L+CRH.L+CRDA.L+DCC.L+DGE.L+DLG.L+DC.L+EZJ.L+EXPN.L+FRES.L+GKN.L+GSK.L+GLEN.L+HMSO.L+HL.L+HIK.L+HSBA.L+IMB.L+INF.L+IHG.L+IAG.L+ITRK.L+INTU.L+ITV.L+JMAT.L+KGF.L+LAND.L+LGEN.L+LLOY.L+LSE.L+MKS.L+MDC.L+MERL.L+MCRO.L+MNDI.L+MRW.L+NG.L+NXT.L+OML.L+PPB.L+PSON.L+PSN.L+POLY.L+PFG.L+PRU.L+RRS.L+RB.L+REL.L+RIO.L+RR.L+RBS.L+RDSA.L+RDSB.L+RMG.L+RSA.L+SGE.L+SBRY.L+SDR.L+SVT.L+SHP.L+SKY.L+SN.L+SMIN.L+SSE.L+STJ.L+STAN.L+SL.L+TW.L+TSCO.L+TPK.L+TUI.L+ULVR.L+UU.L+VOD.L+WTB.L+WOS.L+WPG.L+WPP.L&f=np");

            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(link.openStream());
            ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int n = 0;
            while (-1!=(n=in.read(buf))) {
                out.write(buf, 0, n);
            }
            out.close();
            in.close();
            byte[] response = out.toByteArray();

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
            fos.write(response);
            fos.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("not available");
        }
    }
}
```

I am guessing you would need to implement the `run()` instance but not sure how you would write a program into that.

Comment: I do not see any ExecutorService in your code. Please show what you have tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow the below steps which use `ScheduledExecutorService` as shown below:

**Step (1): You need to move your code into a separate class as shown below:**

```
public TaskRunner implements Runnable {
   public void run() {
        //your code here (logic froom main method)
   }
}
```

**Step(2): Now use `ScheduledExecutorService` as shown below:**

```
public class MySchduler {
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler =
                     Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TaskRunner(), 0, 1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    }
}
```

You can look [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Comment: Thank you for your response! Worked a treat, appreciate your help :)